# Not able to request global modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed two modules globally which are discord.js and request. When I do `npm list -g`, I seem them in there. When I go to my project folder and fire up a command prompt, I type `node app.js` and it says it cannot find discord.js, why is this? I had just reinstalled Windows and this was working perfectly before the reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `npm list -g` you are getting the list of globally installed modules instead of those in the currently installed project.

Globally installed modules reside in something like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, whereas locally installed modules reside in `/your_project/node_modules`.

From the `npm` documentation for `npm ls -g` (aliased in your case to `npm list -g`):

> **global**
>
> - Default: false
> - Type: Boolean
>
> List packages in the global install prefix instead of in the current project.

The Node.js `require` does not look in the global `node_modules` folder, only your local `node_modules` folder.

You can either add your global `node_modules` folder to your `NODE_PATH` environment variable or install using `npm install` without the `-g` flag. When you run `npm install --save <module name>` you install the module in the `node_modules` folder for the current project, which allows your project to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to do `npm install --save <module name>`

Even though it's the answer to my problem, can anybody answer why it did this?

Comment: are you using nvm? are you running `node app.js` from the shell? My guess is that the PATH for node needs to be checked out. The `require` works in odd ways at times. I recommend you this link: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm